Is it true that cats only meow at humans?
It's been said that cats only meow as a way to communicate with their humans. They are not supposed to meow at each other.
After our cat just gave birth to 7 kittens and now  I have to question that theory. The kittens with eyes closed and not knowing humans are around do a fine job of meowing to each other, to mom, or just because they are wanting food.
Makes me question the whole only meow as a way to talk to humans.
Any thoughts on this as to me it just seems like it was just made up because there is not known reason why they meow. Kittens right after mom gets them cleaned up are screaming but to who and why?
Thanks in advance for your responses.

'It's been said that cats only meow as a way to communicate with their humans. They are not supposed to meow at each other.' - Citation needed

Note too that there are vocalizations other than meows.

The idea that adult cats don't meow at each other is still perpetuated, however I'm not convinced it is warranted, at least not for non-feral cats.

There is a plethora of footage on YouTube where outdoor cats wearing small cameras meow at their acquaintances while doing their rounds, clearly in an attempt to communicate.
I've personally witnessed colony cats meowing at each other as well, and one of our three cats even has specific meows that he exclusively uses to communicate with his two mates in order to request cat-on-cat playtime, and a different meow (but somewhat similar in pitch) directed at other cats outside of our enclosed property.

Now this is pure speculation on my part, but a possible explanation could be that once the concept of meowing for results is understood to be working on humans, it isn't far fetched to utilize this form of vocalization on their own kind.
Another angle might be that with their very acute hearing, recognizing a specific cat by voice might be possible far earlier than by scent. Meowing to announce oneself could help facilitate friendly encounters, as other cats might not understand the meaning, but realize "it's that harmless goofball who always meows" and not a threat.
